# No active image found in material even though there is an image texture in the material

Tags: materials, node-editor, texture-baking, error

I've tried replacing the image texture node. I've tried removing it and re-adding it but it still gives me the error that there is no active image found in material. Is there something I'm missing?

[image: My point of view]

Comment: what we see is probably the Musgrave texture plugged into the Roughness, is that your question?

Comment: obviously, as seen in bottom left, the texture does not exist.

Comment: I just saw that. Thank you lol.